# WordPress widget area disapper

Tags: wordpress

I am working on a WordPress site. While adding some widget in widget section, I got some issue.

I add some thing in primary widget area and right widget area, and when I refresh the widget page my added content got disappear although it is displaying in the front-end of WordPress,but now I am not able to edit that content from admin section.

My code is as follows:

```
add_filter( 'sidebars_widgets', 'disable_sidebar_L_widgets' );
function disable_sidebar_L_widgets( $sidebars_widgets ) {
    if (!is_front_page() ) $sidebars_widgets['primary-widget-area'] = false;
    return $sidebars_widgets; }
add_filter( 'sidebars_widgets', 'disable_sidebar_R_widgets' );
function disable_sidebar_R_widgets( $sidebars_widgets ) {
    if (!is_front_page() ) $sidebars_widgets['right-widget-area'] = false;
    return $sidebars_widgets;
}
```

Comment: What I realize that  widget does not disappear when I change my theme.so i think this is theme related problem.currently I am using 1130 theme that is raising problem.

Comment: Finally i got the problem.actually i added some code in function.php to display side bar only on front page,when i comment that code widgte appears in admin section.

Answer (score 0):

Edit functions.php and locate for register_sidebar function. Change the id to small caps example :

register_sidebar( array(
        'name' => __( 'Main Sidebar', ),
        'id' => 'sidebar-1',
        'before_widget' => '',
        'after_widget' => "",
        'before_title' => '',
        'after_title' => '',
    ) );